Movie about students falling in love at university
I'm trying to find a movie about a new girl who arrives to the university and she falls in love with a student who has been studying in the university for many years. 
He loves throwing parties there, is kinda crazy, has curly hair. Soon they end up together, and he travels with the girl to meet her parents.
Edit:
I believe the genre was romance, as the love story between them two was very important. I estimate the film was from the 80's (or it looked so at least). 
The main characters were a boy with black curly hair, and a blonde girl. Both of them were between 20-30. 
The initial setting was in the university and the residence. The girl was invited to a party and this is where she meets the boy. He acts as the party host and he reveals he is still at the university studying because he loves parties so much and don't want them to end. When he goes with her to her parent's house, he lies not saying what he truly does at the university.

This describes about 200 different films. Is there any other details you can provide? Era? Genre? Actors? Setting?

Sounds like Van Wilder

Did the main character have a Bulldog?

This movie sounds like Van Wilder: Party Liaison (2002). Starring Ryan Reynolds as Van Wilder and Tara Reid as Gwen Pearson.
Matching details:

Van (Reynolds) has been going to University for many years


He fails his exams on purpose to stay there

Initial setting is at a residency house party hosted by Van


This is where the girl, Gwen (Reid), meets Van

Van and Gwen get together and have a dinner at Gwen's parents' place


Van fails to tell them why he's at the uni for so long

The movie is a Romantic Comedy
Van has dark curly-ish hair
Gwen has blonde hair

Here's the trailer on YouTube:




Van Wilder was my first thought as well, though they don't actually get together until the end of the movie. There is a dinner party at her parents' house, though, and the OP could be misremembering the flirting as them being together.

Could it be Son-in-Law, with Pauly Shore and Carla Gugino? A small town girl goes to university. Pauly Shore's character is the person in charge of the residential area (sorry, don't know the American names for these!).  He introduces her to parties and helps her dress and behave more outrageously, showing her an old photo of himself as he was when he started university, looking very tidy and conservative. They visit her family where she has to hide her tattoo and he feels out of place, but tries to fit in. From the photo on imdb the hair colour seems different, but his is crazy and curly.
